# Server Hook from VSTS to BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, azure-devops

I have some code hosted in Git in VSTS and I want to sync it with a Git repo in BitBucket. Looking around [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/get-started) it seems like such an integration exists out of the box. If I wanted to do this, is it something that could be real time? Or would it have to be manually synced somewhere. The goal would be that tags/history/everything were replicated between the two or at least from VSTS to BitBucket

Answer (score 0):

Service hooks fire immediately.

Comment: Great, but what would that hook look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync the code by using CI build with git command, similar thread: [How to synchronize VSTS and Github respositories when commits are made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814023/how-to-synchronize-vsts-and-github-respositories-when-commits-are-made)