# Sync BitBucket to VSTS Online on git push

Tags: git, azure-devops, bitbucket, webhooks

Some background information. The company currently uses a lot of software companies to produce their IT-software. Each company has their own GIT implementation that work with their setup up (e.g. testing, building etc.)

The problem is that in order to keep track of this code we have gotten access to a variety of different repositories and git hosting companies (like BitBucket).

The problem we encountered was that some code got inaccessible because some companies have disappeared over the years and this is not an optimal solution.

IT got asked if it was possible to backup all code that are being pushed to the various repos into our own VSTS repos. That way, we would have a copy of all the updated files whenever they are pushed to any of the repos.

An idea was to use a webhook but i am unsure if that is even possible for VSTS to accept incoming data pushes using webhooks from different vendors like BitBucket. It would be like mirroring between their repos and our own repos.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction for how to achieve this or if anyone has a different suggestion to resolve the problem at hand?

(We can always create a .NET service that we host locally which accepts incoming webhook pushes and then, push that data into our VSTS repo. But would rather find an existing solution.)

Comment: Do you mean pushing to git repositories hosted on VSTS (not TFVC repos)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the VSTS builds you can achieve this in a reliable way. You can define a build tied with BitBucket (cloud) and let the build run for every commit in bit bucket and push the downloaded repo to VSTS git using a build task. This will be something simple to implement as well. In case if your bitbucket is on-prem you have to expose it via public url securely and can use as a "External Git" in VSTS build.

A similar implementation is discussed with GitHub in below articles and thread.
https://westerndevs.com/Synchronize-GitHub-Repository-With-VSTS/
https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/leonj/2017/01/24/synchronizing-tfs-2015-and-vsts-with-github/
[How to synchronize VSTS and Github respositories when commits are made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814023/how-to-synchronize-vsts-and-github-respositories-when-commits-are-made)