# How to keep updating azure repo from Git Hub?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I have my repo in GitHub. When I first use Azure repo, I clone that GitHub repo in to Azure repo.

Now, I make some changes in my local machine using git. After that I commit a code in git master branch. Then I did git push to my GitHub master branch. I can see a commit id with comment on GitHub. But some how I am not able to see a that commit in Azure Repo.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

My repo is a private repo, so I sync it to Azure Repo with my credentials.

Comment: How did you `clone the repo`? Did you add a new remote and pushed it by hand?

Comment: Why are you maintaining two separate copies of the same repository?

Comment: Because my company already invested into Git hub and once I move my code to Azure repo, I do not want anything to break. Secondly, I would like to use Azure work items and link those commit tag with work items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to synchronize VSTS and Github respositories when commits are made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814023/how-to-synchronize-vsts-and-github-respositories-when-commits-are-made)

Comment: This  one looks like working on other way. I want to sync from Github to VSTS.

Comment: @KrunalPatel did you find any way of doing what you wanted?